# Redirect to external website with post parameters in JBoss Seam?

Tags: java, jsf, post, redirect, seam

I have to integrate the Moneybooker Payment Service to an existing Seam Application. Regarding to the documentation, I have to pass parameters to moneybookers via POST.

My question is, how to pass parameters via POST to an external website? I know I am able to redirect to an external website via "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("URL")", and I can pass parameters via get to this website. How to do this with a POST?

It would make sense to me to do this with a form with invisible fields as parameters, but I am not able to redirect to an external URL via forms.

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a plain vanilla HTML `<form>` element.

```
<form action="http://moneybooker.com" method="post">
```